# Does total fixed point property implies fixed point property?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. We will say that $X$ has the fixed point property (fpp) iff for every continuous mapping $f:X\to X$, there is a point $x_0\in X$ s.t $f(x_0)=x_0$.

We will say that $X$ has the total fixed point property (tfpp) iff for every continuous **surjective** mapping $f:X\to X$, f has a fixed point.

I am asked to say if any of the next implications are valid:

1. fpp $\implies$ tfpp,
2. tfpp $\implies$ fpp.

The first one is clearly true, but I am having trouble answering 2.

Any hints will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this implication TFPP implies FPP does *not* hold:

Let $X = \mathbb{R} \times \{0\} \cup \{(0,1)\}$ with the topology inherited from the plane; this is just the sum of a copy of the reals with an isolated point $(0,1)$. $X$ does not have the fixed point property, just send $(0,1)$ to $(0,0)$ and all $(x,0)$ to $(x+1, 0)$ for a fixed point free self-map.

But if $f$ is surjective, the only point that can map to $(0,1)$ is $(0,1)$ as the inverse image of this singleton is clopen, so cannot intersect the copy of the reals (unless the whole map is constant, which cannot be). Hence $(0,1)$ is a fixed point of any continuous *onto* function.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you think it will be valid if the space is compact? I think it won't, maybe with the sine of the topologist?

Comment: For a compact example take the sum of a circle and a point.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking in much more complicated spaces, this is so clear.